# Oracle Apex save pasted image into blob

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I found the way [here](https://apextips.blogspot.com/2018/10/acting-when-user-pastes-image.html), how to copy a clipboard image to a region, ad it works well. But I didn't find how can I save this picture into my blob field. Which variable contains the image (maybe it is a javascript variable), and how can I refer to it in the SQL expression (e.g. in a dynamic action)?

Answer (score 0):

create a process like this:

```
declare  
doc_size integer;  
Upload_blob blob;
begin   
--Copy BLOB to Upload_blob variable   
select blob_content   into   Upload_blob   from   APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES   where  name = :FILE_BROWSER;   
--Get BLOB size   
doc_size := dbms_lob.getlength(Upload_blob);
--Copy data to table MyIMAGES_TBL
if doc_size <= 1000000 then   
insert into MyIMAGES_TBL (          IMAGE_NAME, FILENAME,          MIME_TYPE, DOC_SIZE,          CONTENT )   select :FILE_NAME, filename,          mime_type, doc_size,          blob_content   from   APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES   where  name = :FILE_BROWSER;        
--Delete temp files     delete from APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES where name = :FILE_BROWSER;
else   delete from APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES where name = :FILE_BROWSER;
   commit;   
raise_application_error(-20001,'Cannot upload pictures bigger than 1MB!');
end if;
exception when others then     raise_application_error(-20001,'Error when uploading image!');    
end;
```